# Lengthy PHP database results visible

Tags: php, mysql, database, pagination

I have a MYSQL database with several hundred lines of information.
I have the results  displaying how I want them to, but the visibility is hidden on the page. How do I make the results display properly and change the page size to accommodate the lengthy result?

```
foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $t) {
echo "<div style='overflow:visible; height:auto; width:500px;'>$t[name],$t[lab_section],$t[price],$t[link]<br></div>";
}
```

Currently, this is just creating a new div for every line of result because of the

> foreach

statement that is creating the results.

How can I make these results display on the page, without pagination, and without cutting off the results? I would like to scroll through my results.

Comment: This code should be successfully outputting every result of the query to the page.  If there's a styling problem with the page, that would be in the CSS.  Not in the PHP.